# How can i get information about in-app-purchases in Google Play Billing for android

Tags: android, android-billing

I want to get information about how to get detail of already Purchases product with or without internet connection in android studio.

As i know, in google play billing library has 2 method for retrieving the information.

```
1. PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.INAPP);

2. billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(SkuType.INAPP,
                                         new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                          List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK
                && purchasesList != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchasesList) {
                // Process the result.
            }
         }
    }
});
```

But i don't know how to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
This is the way I have implemented In-App Purchase. It is working smoothly. Hope it helps.

mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

                //  Log.d("anupam", responseCode + "");
                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                    for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    //List of purchases
                    }
                } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Sorry, you have canceled purchase Subscription.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Sorry, some error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).build();

        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {

                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.

                    final Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                    for (Purchase sourcePurchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
                        if (sourcePurchase != null) {

                            ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConsumeResponse(final int responseCode, final String purchaseToken) {
                                    // Log.d("anupam2", responseCode + "  <------->  "+ purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() + "  <------->  " + purchaseToken);
                                }
                            };
                            mBillingClient.consumeAsync(sourcePurchase.getPurchaseToken(), listener);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    if (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() > 0) {
                        //  Log.d("anupam3", purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() + "");

                    } else {
                        //  Log.d("anupam4", purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() + "");
                        BillingFlowParams.Builder builder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSku("234r23446").setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                        int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(SplashActivity.this, builder.build());
                        if (responseCode == 7) {

                            //Item already purchased
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! but i have another question if user will purchase a one time product then how can i check  that user have already purchased that product from my main activity without initializing the BillingClient.

Comment: You have to initialize the billing client.  There is no other way.

Comment: So can i make a separate method for BillingClient and call from activity.

Comment: Yes call from the onCreate in the Activity.

Comment: can you please tell me about this (getOriginalJson() method within the Purchase class.)

Comment: and how to use this method getOriginalJson()

Comment: Just copy paste the whole thing in a method and call the method from onCreate. It will work.

Comment: i can not upvote because i don't have 15 reputation

Comment: hey, can you please answer one more question

Comment: how can i make a scrolling page in android studio, and inside the page i want add some text view, image view, grid view and list view. Like a main screen of paytm app. Please tell me.

Comment: actually i don't want to scroll grid view. i only want to scroll, scroll view.

Comment: Hey can you please answer this question :- https://stackoverflow.com/q/57213262/10531874